# Phpmyadmin freezes on query, db too big?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I got two tables (one with 33k rows and another with 7k rows). I want to compare the two tables and delete the rows in which the two id's dont match. But when i send off the query, it freezes phpmyadmin. Could the tables be too big?

```
SELECT * FROM likes LEFT OUTER JOIN uploads on likes.upload_id = uploads.upload_id WHERE uploads.upload_id IS NULL
```

I know databases are meant to handle millions of data, so i'm not sure where the error lies.

Best regards,
Mathias

Comment: What do you mean by "freezes"?

Comment: when phpmyadmin freezes, the script is being executed. Are you sure you have indexes in place? 33k rows is nothing, should not be an issue.

Comment: Cursor looks as if it's working, but nothing happens. 
Pretty sure i got the indexes in place, yeah

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do an explain so you can see what mysql does. This would give a good indication on what how many rows are used.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM likes LEFT OUTER JOIN uploads on likes.upload_id = uploads.upload_id WHERE uploads.upload_id IS NULL
```

you could also use another browser or another session to use show processlist to see how the query is executed.

Answer (score 2):

Tables probably aren't too big but PhpMyAdmin's query timeout might be an issue if the script takes a long time to finish. Try and [change the timeout](http://situsnya.wordpress.com/2008/09/11/change-script-timeout-in-phpmyadmin/) or don't use PhpMyAdmin at all. See if you are able to so the query using command line on the server (or some other tool).

See also:

- [how to import a very large query over phpmyadmin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427297/how-to-import-a-very-large-query-over-phpmyadmin)
- [Mysql phpMyadmin Timeout Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499116/mysql-phpmyadmin-timeout-question)

Answer (score 0):

Does Freeze imply it's working but never updates/ never "finishes" the task?

If so,
I have had a similar thing and found they've been due to having more than one index on a column, for example a column has a PRIMARY index and an index named after the column, so check your indexes

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes run large import "queries" that can take a few hours to process. (I untick "Partial import -> Allow the interruption of an import...".)

phpMyAdmin will not respond in the browser I started the queries in, even if I try to reload the page, but if I go to a browser on another machine with (I assume) a different IP address phpMyAdmin responds fine.

On the other browser I then issue the SQL command `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` to [monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638689/how-to-see-full-query-from-show-processlist) and kill that long running query if need be.

Answer (score 0):

you can just uncheck to two option in import

1 - Allow the interruption of an import in case the script detects it is close to the PHP timeout limit. (This might be a good way to import large files, however it can break transactions.)

2- Enable foreign key checks